# How do I solve this SQL interview question?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm practicing for my upcoming SQL interview using questions from bigtechinterviews.com and am currently stuck on my solution (See my solution below).

**Prompt:** Write a query to find active users on the Free plan to contact them 1 day before their trial expires and notify them of the number of active servers they are using. Return the email, the number of active servers, and the date they should be contacted. (Hint: A free trial lasts 14 days.)

Table: users

| user_id | email | signup | active | plan_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Julius_Ashwell8914@mafthy.com | current_timestamp::DATE-11 | true | 1 |
| 2 | Mya_Tobin3533@ovock.tech | current_timestamp::DATE-21 | false | 2 |
| 3 | Chuck_Higgs2765@kideod.biz | current_timestamp::DATE-12 | false | 2 |
| 4 | Daniel_Bryant6167@acrit.org | current_timestamp::DATE-3 | true | 3 |
| 5 | Erick_Hammond5462@naiker.biz | current_timestamp::DATE-5 | false | 1 |
| 6 | Jacob_Sanchez2328@bulaffy.com | current_timestamp::DATE-8 | true | 2 |
| 7 | Denis_Hooper2237@extex.org | current_timestamp::DATE-6 | true | 3 |
| 8 | Hayden_Thomas1923@liret.org | current_timestamp::DATE-12 | true | 1 |

Table: servers

| user_id | server | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 67.55.37.78 | true |
| 5 | 37.61.109.175 | false |
| 3 | 158.66.86.52 | false |
| 2 | 194.17.5.72 | false |
| 7 | 25.132.11.177 | true |
| 8 | 159.235.115.252 | false |
| 6 | 40.23.107.96 | true |
| 6 | 168.195.126.210 | true |
| 5 | 184.202.205.222 | false |
| 1 | 34.171.164.42 | true |
| 3 | 38.231.102.133 | false |
| 6 | 189.44.114.58 | true |
| 4 | 56.200.112.239 | true |
| 1 | 134.214.244.247 | false |
| 4 | 253.146.50.201 | true |
| 5 | 77.181.43.159 | false |
| 1 | 242.71.73.107 | true |
| 2 | 64.175.228.245 | false |
| 5 | 124.80.68.144 | false |
| 8 | 239.90.220.90 | true |
| 6 | 74.182.172.182 | true |
| 6 | 146.180.155.33 | true |
| 3 | 7.1.210.72 | false |
| 5 | 240.126.4.87 | false |

Table: plans

| plan_id | plan_type | supported_servers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | free | 1 |
| 2 | paid | 3 |
| 3 | pro | 5 |

Full question linked here: https://app.bigtechinterviews.com/challenge/2RE4RjguRPJxarKxtIUJDD

Attempted Solution:

```
SELECT
     u.email
    ,COUNT(s.server) servers
    ,signup::DATE + interval '13 days' target_day
FROM
    users u 
JOIN
    "plans" p
ON
    p.plan_id = u.plan_id
     AND p.plan_type = 'free'
LEFT JOIN
    servers s
ON
    s.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE
    u.active = true
GROUP BY 
    1,3;
```

the expected output is:

| email | servers | target_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Julius_Ashwell8914@mafthy.com | 3 | 2022-08-25T00:00:00.000Z |
| Hayden_Thomas1923@liret.org | 1 | 2022-08-24T00:00:00.000Z |

current output is:

| email | servers | target_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hayden_Thomas1923@liret.org | 2 | 2022-10-10T00:00:00.000Z |
| Julius_Ashwell8914@mafthy.com | 4 | 2022-10-11T00:00:00.000Z |

Comment: Hey @mkrieger1, the expected output is: 


|email                         |servers |target_day              |
+------------------------------+--------+------------------------+    
|Julius_Ashwell8914@mafthy.com |3       |2022-08-25T00:00:00.000Z|
|Hayden_Thomas1923@liret.org   |1       |2022-08-24T00:00:00.000Z|

Comment: And my current output is, 

email servers target_day
Hayden_Thomas1923@liret.org 2 2022-10-10T00:00:00.000Z
Julius_Ashwell8914@mafthy.com 4 2022-10-11T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: Please edit your question to add further details. Comments are not a good place for them.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: @DannySlor PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT u.email
     , COALESCE(s.servers, 0) AS servers
     , u.signup + 13 AS target_day
FROM   users   u
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT s.user_id, count(*) AS servers 
   FROM   servers s
   WHERE  s.user_id = u.user_id
   AND    s.active
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) s ON true
WHERE  u.active
AND    u.plan_id = (SELECT plan_id FROM plans WHERE plan_type = 'free')
AND    u.signup > CURRENT_DATE - 14;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ug9XQcsv)

This avoids `GROUP BY` in the outer `SELECT`.

`LEFT JOIN` to keep users without active servers in the loop. Consequently, `COALESCE` in the outer `SELECT` list.

`LATERAL` because I assume only a very small percentage of all users qualify, so it's cheaper to aggregate servers only for the select few.

`signup > CURRENT_DATE - 14` to exclude older rows, which must have been informed already. Maybe just removes one day, maybe more - depending on undisclosed information how those free plans are inactivated exactly.

Answer (score 0):

We need to get all the active servers for all the active users that are on a free plan. In your solution you counted inactive servers as well.

```
select   u.email
        ,count(*)         as servers
        ,max(u.signup+13) as target_day
from     users u join servers s using(user_id) join plans p using(plan_id)
where    s.active = true
and      u.active = true
and      p.plan_type = 'free'
group by u.email
```

| email | servers | target_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hayden_Thomas1923@liret.org | 1 | 2022-10-11 |
| Julius_Ashwell8914@mafthy.com | 3 | 2022-10-12 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ixUEyX1f)

Answer (score 0):

your solution includes all servers, not only the active ones. Add a condition to your left join on servers same style as you already have done with the join on plans:

```
SELECT
     u.email
    ,COUNT(s.server) servers
    ,signup::DATE + interval '13 days' target_day
FROM
    users u 
JOIN
    "plans" p
ON
    p.plan_id = u.plan_id
     AND p.plan_type = 'free'
LEFT JOIN
    servers s
ON
    s.user_id = u.user_id and s.active = true <---- only active ones
WHERE
    u.active = true
GROUP BY 
    1,3;
```